# Minimum number of solutions for $f=g$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f, g : [−1, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be odd functions whose derivatives are continuous. You
are given that $|g(x)| < 1$ for all $x \in [−1, 1], f(−1) = −1, f(1) = 1$ and $f'(0)<g'(0)$. Then find the minimum possible number of solutions to the equation
$f(x) = g(x)$ in the interval $[−1, 1]$.

My answer is $3$. Because $0$ is a trivial solution and in a neighborhood of $0$ the function $g(x)-f(x)$ is increasing. Now applying Intermediate value property we get another two solutions.

Comment: You have proved that there are at least three solutions. But the minimum number could be higher than $3$. So find an  example where you have exactly $3$ solutions.

Comment: Sir, if we consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{3x}{2x^2+2}$, then there are exactly $3$ solutions.

Comment: Good job. This example works fine.